# How to live search an html drop down menu

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, autocomplete

First things first, I have to be specific, it is drop down list with a live search, and not a live search with a drop down list of suggestions. Most of my search work showed me how to create an autocomplete search, but I want the drop down list of suggestions to be there before and during the search.

Picture this, you have a drop down list where user can select the type of food he likes, say apple, orange and banana. Let's say it's not just these three fruits, there's a list of about 100 fruits. Scrolling wont be an issue if he is to select apple, which is at the top of list, but he has to scroll all the way to the bottom to select orange. So instead, I include an input field, so when he types in "o", the drop down list automatically lists all fruits starting with "o" .

It would be easier to just let the user search initially and bring up suggestions based on input, but then, this code is useful when one wants the user to see the drop down list of options first, and also give him the option to search the list for a specific option.

I would appreciate more if the code uses php.

Thanks in advance.

- Update
  After some little more research, I have edited the topic to suit my need better. https://www.html5andbeyond.com/live-search-a-html-list-using-jquery-no-plugin-needed/ - this is the link to a code to create a live search on an HTML list. The difference now is, this time, it should be a drop down menu. The user clicks on the drop down menu, which shows a drop down list, and also a search field to live search the list. :)

Answer (score 0):

Like this way?

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

your search data, you can use ajax to connect to the database.